# How to properly scope User attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, scope, scoping

How to achieve simple scoping in your views such as:

```
<% if @user.admin %>
```

where "admin" is the following scope in user.rb:

```
scope :admin, where(role: "admin")
```

there is a column Role which is a string in the Users table

I've done the same thing before with another Model (but not a devise user model) to which I could later call

```
<% if objective.completed %>
```

right after calling an each method in the objectives.

**However**
When I do the exact same thing to a user model I get an

```
undefined method `admin' for #<User:0x00000107e39038>
```

How could I make it work? I've been digging for hours.

For a no scope workaround try:

```
<% if @user.role == "admin" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't use scopes this way. Scopes are used as class methods, so if you run

```
User.admin
```

it returns list of users matching given condition. What you need is an instance method. Add it to your user.rb file:

```
def admin?
  admin == 'admin'
end
```

and you will be able to use it in your view:

```
- if @user.admin?
```

anyways, you should definitely reconsider storing roles as string in `users` table. Try to create another table called `roles`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! For others who may encounter this issue the easiest workaround is:
       <% if user.role == "admin" %>

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are usually class level methods, having said that, how can you access it with an instance. I think, that is why the error says undefined method.